# MySQL cross-reference between 2 databases with 2 different users

Tags: mysql, sql, database, cross-reference, privilege

Assume that I have 2 databases named `db1` and `db2`. For some reasons, our hosting service only allows 1 user per database. I have `user1` is administrator of `db1`, and `user2` as the administrator of `db2`. Here is an example query:

```
SELECT *
FROM db1.table1, db2.table2
WHERE db1.table1.column1 = db2.table2.column2;
```

The above SQL works if `user1` (or `user2`) is administrator of both `db1` and `db2`. But in my case, it's not. That's why the SQL doesn't work because `user1` doesn't have privilege on `db2` and vice versa.

How can I cross-reference between these 2 databases?

Thanks.

Comment: If i understand correctly you want to make a join between two tables on 2 diferent databases? If that's the case, the login you use must have select privileges on both databases. You can't avoid that. It doesn't need to be administrator.

Comment: If you can only create one user per database, you should consider changing providers.  This is a really odd limit and it totally useless in any system of significant complexity where you want to create specific access controls for different users/applications, which is common practice.